# How to write a method that takes in a number and returns a string placing a single hyphen before and after each odd number?

Tags: ruby, regex

The one exception is that the returned string cannot begin or end with a hyphen, and each odd digit is permitted only a **single hyphen** before and after each odd digit. For example:

```
def hyphenate(number)
  # code
end

hyphenate(132237847) # should return "1-3-22-3-7-84-7"

"-1-3-22-3-7-84-7-"  # incorrect because there is a hyphen before and after
                     # each beginning and ending odd digit respectively.

"1--3-22-3--7-84-7" # Also incorrect because there is more than one
                    # single hyphen before and after each odd digit
```

Comment: you should also add what you tried...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to match a non-word boundary `\B` *(that will match a position between two digits)* followed or preceded with an odd digit:

```
number.to_s.gsub(/\B(?=[13579])|\B(?<=[13579])/, '-')
```

Since the same position can't be matched twice, you avoid the problem of consecutive hyphens.

[rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/b7hYbsfVAI)

[with the replacement](https://regex101.com/r/pX7Qkf/1)

Comment: @muistooshort: thanks for the to_s, what a strange behavior.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to convert the number to a string, `String#split` the string on odd digits (using a group so that the odd digit delimiters get into the output), clean up the stray `''` strings that `String#split` will produce, and put it back together with `Array#join`:

```
number.to_s.split(/([13579])/).reject(&:empty?).join('-')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def hyphenate(number)
  test_string = ''
  # Convert the number to a string then iterate over each character
  number.to_s.each_char do |n|
    # If the number is divisible by 2 then just add it to the string
    # else it is an odd number then add it with the hyphens
    n.to_i % 2 == 0 ? test_string += n : test_string += "-#{n}-"
  end
  # Remove the first character of the string if it is a hyphen
  test_string = test_string[1..-1] if test_string.start_with?('-')
  # Remove the last character of the string if it is a hyphen
  test_string = test_string[0..-2] if test_string.end_with?('-')
  # Return the string and replace all double hyphens with a single hyphen
  test_string.gsub('--', '-')
end

puts hyphenate(132237847)
```

Returns "1-3-22-3-7-84-7"

Comment: You could use `n.to_i.odd?` instead of the explicit modulus if you wanted to cut down on the punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach for taking a number and returning it in string form with its odd digits surrounded by hyphens:

```
def hyphenate(number)
  result = ""
  number.digits.reverse.each do |digit|
    result << (digit.odd? ? "-#{digit}-" : digit.to_s)
  end
  result.gsub("--", "-").gsub(/(^-|-$)/, "")
end

hyphenate(132237847)
# => "1-3-22-3-7-84-7"
```

Hope it helps!